# How to handle dispute event in webhook?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm a amateur php developer. I accepts stripe payments in my php website as one-time payments. I've integrated it correctly according to stripe website docs. (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time#create-checkout-session). I'm getting checkout.session.created event from stripe webhook and I store it in my database as a completed payment. ( Advise me if I'm doing wrong ). This is the sample event data that stripe triggers as checkout.session.completed event.

```js
{
  "id": "evt_123",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2019-03-14",
  "created": 1561420781,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_test_123",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel",
      "client_reference_id": null,
      "customer": "cus_123",
      "customer_email": null,
      "display_items": [],
      "mode": "setup",
      "setup_intent": "seti_1123",
      "submit_type": null,
      "subscription": null,
      "success_url": "https://example.com/success"
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "checkout.session.completed"
}
```

But I need to handle webhook events for disputes. If a paid user opens dispute, I need to know it. How stripe notifies me it via webhook ? If stripe notifies me, How do I find parent payment ?. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

webbhook is a url provided by you to stripe, on which stripe will be sending data, just like how you send data from a form to your site.

You should follow stripe docs for it, https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events and https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally edit your original post to include the 'answer' you added yesterday - and remove that answer - as Stackoverflow isn't the same as a forum

The Dispute object contains a [Payment Intent ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/disputes/object#dispute_object-payment_intent) and you can [list / 'retrieve' the Checkout Session for that Payment Intent ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-payment_intent), so that's how you get it.